# i have problem with sharing a folder through programming using c#?

Tags: c#

here is my code it shares the folder but that does not work correctly when i want to access it , it shows access denied help required,

```
private static void ShareFolder(string FolderPath, string ShareName, string Description)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a ManagementClass object
            ManagementClass managementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Share");
            // Create ManagementBaseObjects for in and out parameters
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = managementClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
            ManagementBaseObject outParams;
            // Set the input parameters
            inParams["Description"] = Description;
            inParams["Name"] = ShareName;
            inParams["Path"] = FolderPath;
            inParams["Type"] = 0x0; // Disk Drive
            //Another Type:
            //DISK_DRIVE = 0x0;
            //PRINT_QUEUE = 0x1;
            //DEVICE = 0x2;
            //IPC = 0x3;
            //DISK_DRIVE_ADMIN = 0x80000000;
            //PRINT_QUEUE_ADMIN = 0x80000001;
            //DEVICE_ADMIN = 0x80000002;
            //IPC_ADMIN = 0x8000003;
            //inParams["MaximumAllowed"] = int maxConnectionsNum;
            // Invoke the method on the ManagementClass object
            outParams = managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
            // Check to see if the method invocation was successful

            if ((uint)(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value) != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to share directory. Because Directory is already shared or directory not exist");
            }//end if

        }//end try
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error!");
        }//end catch
    }//End Method
```

Comment: I suggest you show ex.ToString() instead of ex.Message. There may be much more information that you're not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add permissions to the shared folders. This post [Adding Permissions to a shared folder using WMI and Microsoft .Net](http://hamidshahid.blogspot.com/2009/03/adding-permissions-to-shared-folder.html) explains the steps in detail.

Excerpt from the post

> To assign permission to the user, the
>   following needs to be done
>
> 1. Get hold of the Shared folder object’s setting and extract its
>      security descriptor.
> 2. Extract Access Control List (ACL) from the security descriptor.
> 3. Get hold of the user account object and extract its security
>      descriptor.
> 4. Create a Windows Trustee object for the user using its security
>      descriptor.
> 5. Create an Access Control Entry (ACE) using the Trustee object.
> 6. Add Access Control Entry to Access Control List.
> 7. Assign List back to Security Descriptor for the folder
> 8. Reassign security descriptor to the shared folder.

Answer (score 1):

Return Values

Returns one of the values in the following table or any other value to indicate an error.

0 – Success

2 – Access denied

8 – Unknown failure

9 – Invalid name

10 – Invalid level

21 – Invalid parameter

22 – Duplicate share

23 – Redirected path

24 – Unknown device or directory

25 – Net name not found

Answer (score 0):

Where are you accessing the shared folder from? If from another computer, make sure you have given read privileges on that folder to the computer that you are accessing it from.. Hope this helps...

Thanks,
Ram